# Elasticsearch: Index arrays which contain nested objects with the Java API without predefined mapping?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way to index arrays which contain nested objects with the Java API without predefined mapping?

I would like to create the following structure:

```
"amazingArray": [
  { "uId": "123",  "cars": ["fastCar", "slowCar"]},
  { "uId": "234", "cars": ["niceCar", "badCar"]},
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XContentBuilder object = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
 .startArray("amazingArray")
  .startObject()
   .field("uId","123")
   .startArray("cars")
    .value("fastCar")
    .value("slowCar")
   .endArray()
  .endObject()

  .startObject()
   ...
  .endObject()
 .endArray();
```